# video overlay over div issue in chrome

Tags: html, video

I can able to play video in ie8+,i have a issue while playing in chrome, i hide this video over a div, it works fine in ie but in chrome , it overlays above div in chrome, i tried with z-index to reduce but of no use.

```
<object id='mediaPlayer' width="320" height="285" 
  classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' 
    codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701'
  standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-oleobject'>
  <param name='fileName' value="celebration.wmv">
  <param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
  <param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
  <param name='autoStart' value="false">
  <param name='showControls' value="true">
 <param name="uiMode" value="none"/>
<param name="windowlessVideo" value="true"/>
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>

  <param name='loop' value="true">
  <embed type='application/x-mplayer2'
    pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
    id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1' 
    bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1' 
    showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="270" height="220"
    src="celebration.wmv" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="true">
  </embed>
  </object>
```